# Angular drop down with adjustable multiple columns

Tags: html, angular, angular6, angular7, angular-ngselect

I need a drop down for angular 6/7 with adjustable multiple columns as shown below,

[image]

Where I should be able to adjust the width of the columns by dragging. I googled but I couldn't find a proper library. If there is any library where I can overcome this requirement please suggest me or should I write the whole functionality from scratch. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have a similar scenario to implement. Would appreciate any answers. So far couldn't find any solution that'd fit into my problem

Answer (score 0):

I've used [ngx-datatable](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/) before and it has resizable columns.  Perhaps you could incorporate that into a dropdown.